# Google doesnt list my website

Tags: seo, google

1 month ago I created one website and without doing anything I entered exact domain in google and it was shown as it suposed to..Now I created another project and after 3 days there is no sign of my website on google even if I enter exact name of it.. How can I push it to google??

Answer (score 2):

Visit Google Search Console, verify your page and add a sitemap. Here's an example how your sitemap should looks like: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en&ref_topic=4581190

Have you tried to query "site:yourdomain.com"? It can be helpful. Did you earn some backlinks? And yes, add your URL here: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?continue=/addurl

Comment: Thanks for that. It was interesting as I didnt do any of that with my last website and it got listed asap.. The current website has no links at all apart the main page index.. you can check yaa.io to see what I mean..

Comment: It looks like yaa.io has been index. Avoid keywords in meta tag, it doesn't influence on Google anymore.

Comment: Yeah i did manual push..How keywords come keywords makes no difference? So I have just to delete them ? :(

Comment: You don't have to delete them, but keywords in meta tag (<meta name="keywords" content="let's, write, some, keywords">) doesn't affect your Google ranking. Check out the following url for more information: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html

Answer (score 1):

If you just wait for Google to find your website by itself, it may take while before it finds a link to your new website(Do any links to the new website exist?).

So if you want it to be found there must be pages out there linking to your new website. Having these also helps your ranking but that's another story.

If you don't want to wait for Google to stumble upon your website, you can help Google out.

1. First get a Google accoutn if you don't have one yet.
2. Go to [google webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools)
3. set up your new website as a new property
4. if your website has a sitemap.xml go to webmaster tool / Crawl / Sitemaps and add your URL to your sitemap.xml
5. Go to webmaster tool / Crawl / Fetch as Google and click Fetch
6. After it completes the Fetch you can click Submit to Index, be sure to choose 'Crawl this URL and its direct links'

Now Google has found your website. It's still up to Google for determining how long it will take to show up in the index, but you have done all that you could to speed up the process.

Comment: After I fetch my website it shows an error "Temporarily unreachable" for some reason..

Comment: @StuckBetweenTrees you can see at google support what this message means: 
 -  Fetch as Google can’t currently fetch your URL because the server took too long to reply.
OR
 - Fetch as Google cancelled your fetch because too many consecutive requests were made to the server for different URLs. source: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en

Comment: Thats werid..Well I cant do anything about that tho.. I dont know why my website takes too long for google to respond or smt.. Anyways..I did all the steps for that and I will check within the week if its listed or not.. Thanks for your help Marco